# SSH Beaglebone via ethernet port or Host USB

Tags: ssh, beagleboard, beagleboneblack

I am still new to Beagle-bone black and was having fun until the USB device jack through which I used to SSH accidentally detached from the Beagle-Bone black. I am having a hard time getting the USB device jack (USB mini A/B type) soldered back to its place. That has forced me to look for other options to SSH device listed below.

1.) Ethernet cable. I tried to SSH at the default address 192.168.7.2 and port 22 by connecting a LAN cable from my PC to Beagle-Bone but it didn't work. Any inputs on this would be really helpful.

2.) USB device. I though haven't tried to SSH by connecting a Male USB to USB cable from PC to the bigger USB device jack on Beagle-Bone, but I guess that won't be possible.

3.) HDMI port. Its the last option I could think before going back to soldering the USB device port or buying a new one. 
I am thinking of connecting it to an output device via HDMI cable and a keyboard via USB device port and then enabling remote connection on the device and then accessing it via ethernet cable.

Any help or reference or shared experience with respect to above will be really helpful. I haven't tried the above methodologies as I still have to order a couple of things. I would do that once I have a certain conviction on any of the above.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make it work without USB adapter you require a FTDI cable (USB to serial Adapter), power adapter, CAT5(Ethernet) cable.

First of all connect CAT5(Ethernet) cable from Your board to Laptop or PC, Next connect FTDI cable from USB Port of Laptop to serial port of Beagle Bone Black connect the pins as shown in figure[image]).

If you are using Ubuntu run Minicom -s and in the setup configure port to ttyUSB0, save the settings and plugin power adapter you can start your session and work with the board.

If you are using windows use putty or hyperterminal.

Answer (score 2):

For others searching for help,

To connect Beaglebone black to Ubuntu system, via Ethernet cable,

Power up your BeagleBone
 Connect the Ethernet cable
 run ifconfig on your main system and see the Ethernet port

for example:

```
    $ ifconfig  
    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 18:03:73:70:d8:fa  
              inet addr:10.42.0.1  Bcast:10.42.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::1a03:73ff:fe70:d8fa/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:7547 errors:1 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:1
              TX packets:5126 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:11
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:9630936 (9.6 MB)  TX bytes:422695 (422.6 KB)

    eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 78:a5:04:cd:e7:52  
              inet6 addr: fe80::7aa5:4ff:fecd:e752/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:52 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:1125 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:8766 (8.7 KB)  TX bytes:272946 (272.9 KB)

    lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
              inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
              inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
              UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
              RX packets:29792 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:29792 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:5627707 (5.6 MB)  TX bytes:5627707 (5.6 MB)

    wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 38:59:f9:5f:69:06  
              inet addr:192.168.43.79  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::3a59:f9ff:fe5f:6906/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:111262 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:121625 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:78921601 (78.9 MB)  TX bytes:17154117 (17.1 MB)
```

So, as you can see the eth0 is connected with ip address 10.42.0.1
We now know that beaglebone would have an ip like 10.42.0.*

I further used nmap scan to find the ip address of beaglebone 
as

```
    $ nmap -F 10.42.0.*

    Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-02-19 01:09 IST

    Nmap scan report for 10.42.0.1
    Host is up (0.0013s latency).
    Not shown: 97 closed ports
    PORT    STATE SERVICE
    53/tcp  open  domain
    139/tcp open  netbios-ssn
    445/tcp open  microsoft-ds

    Nmap scan report for 10.42.0.79
    Host is up (0.0023s latency).
    Not shown: 95 closed ports
    PORT     STATE SERVICE
    22/tcp   open  ssh
    80/tcp   open  http
    3000/tcp open  ppp
    3389/tcp open  ms-wbt-server
    8080/tcp open  http-proxy

    Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 3.30 seconds
```

So, as the nmap result shows, the ip address of beaglebone black is 10.42.0.79 and you can ssh over that ip address.