# How to use tftp when the host do not have IP address

Tags: ip, ethernet, beagleboneblack

I am trying to use tftp for update images on my BBB. For that I read tftp tutorials
http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Booting_Linux_kernel_using_U-Boot

It says that I have to connect one ethernet cable from host pc to BBB, and then use

```
/sbin/ifconfig
```

to get the IP of the host. 
But I have only one ethernet port on PC that is connected to internet via LAN. If I remove internet connection and connect other end of cable to BBB
I see this

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:97:5a:bf:d7:79  
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba97:5aff:febf:d779/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5637926 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3011756 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8323844259 (8.3 GB)  TX bytes:205728188 (205.7 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:27842 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:27842 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2756628 (2.7 MB)  TX bytes:2756628 (2.7 MB)
```

So there is no IP address shown.
How then I can get server IP?

Answer (score 0):

The problem of not getting IP address can usually be solved :

`System settings >> Network >> Wired >> Options >> IPv4 Settings`, and then try these changes

`Method : Shared to other computers`
or
`Method : Automatic (DHCP)`
then reconnect the board.

If all this doesn't work, you'll probably have to do this manually.

`Method : Manual`
click `Add`
`Address : 10.42.0.3`
`Netmast : 255.255.255.252`
`Gateway : 0.0.0.0`

If now you have the ip address you can then move to this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35490953/4229514